# quantile vs ecdf results

Tags: r, quantile, ecdf

I am trying to use ecdf, but I am not sure if I am doing it right. My ultimate purpose is to find what quantile corresponds to a specific value. As an example:

```
sample_set <- c(20, 40, 60, 80, 100) 
# Now I want to get the 0.75 quantile:
quantile(x = sample_set, probs = 0.75)
#result:
75% 
80
# Let's use ecdf
ecdf(x = sample_set) (80)
#result
0.8
```

Why is there this discrepancy? Am I doing some trivial mistake, or it depends on the way quantile makes its calculations?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Maybe the calculations would make more sense if you looked at `plot(ecdf(x = sample_set)); abline(h = 0.75,col = "blue")`? Certainly one (or both) of those directions is ambiguous...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two points. First, as you guessed, it depends on the way `quantile` makes its calculations. Specifically, it depends on the parameter `type`. What you might want to choose is `type = 1`, since then it corresponds to the *inverse of empirical distribution function* (see `?quantile`). Second, since `ecdf` gives a discrete, step function, i.e. the ecdf is not strictly increasing, you cannot get exact equality because of the way quantile is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function#Definition) (see the second formula).

Comment: I assume you mean the ecdf is not *strictly* increasing. Its an increasing function in the often used sense of monotonic non-decreasing.

Comment: @A.Webb, yes, that is what I meant. I will add this word to avoid confusion.